# Do OTA updates accumulate if you let them be? Or are they strictly incremental?

Tags: nexus-5, ota-update

I'm on a Nexus 5 running 5.0. I used to get a system update notification for 5.0.1, but since I have Xposed, I decided to wait. After a while, I started getting an OTA notification for 5.1. What will happen if I choose to update? Will it automatically first install 5.0.1 and then 5.1? Or do I need to search online for an OTA zip for 5.0.1, install that and then proceed with 5.1?

Comment: I never encounter this "problem" (well, I'm rooted and always flash the full image file when it's available), but I somewhat believe you don't need to search for previous OTA for reasons: it's not user-friendly at all and very troublesome for casual users, when Google is trying their best to make it available for all. I don't have any references at the moment though.

Comment: The OTA zip size for 5.0 to 5.0.1 is 13.27MB. 5.0.1 to 5.1 is 220.68MB. But 5.0 to 5.1 is 220.81MB. o.O So what should I understand? It's clearly not A + B = C.